# Elastic Search: query search_as_you_type field only at the begining of the input

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a mapping like so on Elastic Search

```
   {
      mappings: {
        properties: {
          score: { type: 'double' },
          name: { type: 'search_as_you_type' }
        }
      }
    }
```

and a query like so

```
{
        sort: [{ score: 'asc' }, '_score'],
        query: {
            multi_match: {
              query: text,
              type: 'bool_prefix',
              fields: [
                'name',
                'name._2gram',
                'name._3gram',
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

The goal is to have auto-complete feature on "name" sorted by "score" starting at the beginning of the name.

so if the search text is "goo"
it should match "google.com" but not "mail.google.com"

right now it seems to do both prefix and infix completion, how can I limit it to prefix completion?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [section describing this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html#search-as-you-type) in the official documentation now. You can use the root field on the `search_as_you_type` mapping for this, I think that'd be like so for your use-case:

```
{
  "sort": [{ "score": "asc" }, "_score"],
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name": "insert query here"
    }
  }
}
```